# How would @synchronized work if called on separate threads?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface Controller ()

@end

@implementation Controller  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

If I add  `@synchronized` will the code behave as a mutex lock that will lock until the thread finishes?

Comment: `@synchronized` is only useful when used with multiple threads.

Comment: Are you actually asking about using `@synchronized` in `-viewDidLoad`?